# MySQL doesn't seem to work

Tags: php

So I made my first database online. I used phpmyadmin, I created the table and the user.
Now I'd like to show the table on a page of my site, as well as giving the possibility to people to edit the database from the site.
My problem is that the database does not work: it doesn't connect. I have no idea what to do.
My database is called **letstenf_santi** and my table **passeggeri**.
This is the code I'm trying to use to show the table on the site.

```
<?php 
//establishing connection
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
//selecting a database
mysql_select_db('letstenf_santi');
$sql  = 'SELECT * FROM `letstenf_santi`.`passeggeri`';
$records=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>mostra</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<table width="300" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
 <tr>
<th>id pass</th>
<th>nome</th>
<th>eta</th>
<th>sesso</th>
 </tr>
 <?php
 while($pass=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
  echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$pass['idpasseggero']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$pass['nome']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$pass['eta']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$pass['sesso']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
 }
 ?>
</table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: deprecated syntax detected

Comment: What's the error you're getting ?

Comment: none. it just doesn't work. i don't know what to do

Comment: `mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());` to test problem!

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions. They have been outright **removed** from PHP (as of version 7). Please learn newer methods such as PDO. In particular, you can set PDO to run in Exception mode, and this will make it extremely clear when things aren't working as expected (whereas `mysql_` functions tended to be quite silent on the matter)

Comment: does not work as in "blank page" or as "page is there, but info from database is not shown"?

Comment: with mysql, you have to get and display the errors yourself, as well as test the result of the query for this purpose. If you don't do it, for you there are no errors.. but, well, they probably are.

Comment: First of all mysql is deprecated so please use mysqli or pdo instead.

Comment: So what should I do? The page is just blank, doesn't show anything

Comment: Use error reporting and check your logs. If using PHP 7 you have undefined function errors.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this,
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('letstenf_santi');

you can try this,

$connection=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

$db=mysql_select_db('letstenf_santi',$connection);

Comment: please change this "mysql_fetch_assoc" into this "mysql_fetch_array"

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "letstenf_santi";//your db name

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";//replace table name with your table name
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); ?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>mostra</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<table width="300" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
 <tr>
<th>id pass</th>
<th>nome</th>
<th>eta</th>
<th>sesso</th>
 </tr>
<?php if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['idpasseggero']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['nome']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['eta']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['sesso']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```